# Regex - find a string and jump immediately to the next line

Tags: regex, notepad++, textpad

For instance I am looking for something in a bigger text file - very simple for example a string of three digits with `\d{3}` . What I want to do is: when notepad++/textpad has found the first matching string in a line (and has replaced it with something else) it should jump immediately into the next line.

How can I accomplish that?

I tried `\r\n` , but in this case textpad finds not the first string with three digits in the line, but always the last. And notepad++ doesn't find anything at all.

I cannot use `^` either because there are some random words (one, two, three or even foru or five) before the digits I try to find and replace.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you have to **include all the remaining of your line into the matching pattern**.

For example, let's say that you search for `\d{3}` and have the following data:

```
qweqwe 123 rrr 445
test tetst
41 423 456
```

**Search for**: `\d{3}(.*$)`

**Replace**: `REPLACEMENT$1`

Will give you the following result:

```
qweqwe REPLACEMENT rrr 445
test tetst
41 REPLACEMENT 456
```

If you didn't had included the remaining line (`.*`) the result would be:

```
qweqwe REPLACEMENT rrr REPLACEMENT
test tetst
41 REPLACEMENT REPLACEMENT
```

In Notepad++ to make this work, you must leave the ". matches newline" option unchecked.

Comment: Yes this works perfect! Thanks! Why do you use the $ for the end of the line and not the ^ for the start?

Comment: You could use `^` too, for example search: `^(.*?)\d{3}`, replace: `$1REPLACEMENT` would produce the same results! Please note that now we had to use `.*?` which is a non-greedy (AKA lazy) match. The only reason I chose the `$` is because if I were to describe it in words, the wording it is closer to your title "find pattern and jump to the next line" than `^` which I would describe as "match the first occurrence of pattern in every line".